# Learning Python the Hard Way ex40, don't understand Study Drill 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex40.html

> Put the lyrics in a separate variable, then pass that variable to the class to use instead.

I don't understand how to do this, and I'm not even entirely sure what he means by that. Does he mean to define the variables within the class?

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self, lyrics):
        self.lyrics = lyrics

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line

happy_bday = Song(["Happy birthday to you",
                   "I don't want to get sued",
                   "So I'll stop right there"])

bulls_on_parade = Song(["They rally around the family",
                        "With pockets full of shells"])

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()

bulls_on_parade.sing_me_a_song()
```

Comment: No, something along the lines of `lyrics = "sing me a song!!" song = Song(lyrics)`.

Comment: ... the class only works with an array of strings limelights, but yeah, basically just assign the lyrics to a variable first

Answer (score 1):

I just think he means to do something like

```
 lyricsImagine = ["Imagine there's no countries","It isn't hard to do","Nothing to kill or die for"]
 songImagine = Song(lyricsImagine)
 songImagine.sing_me_a_song()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think he is meaning you should do it like this:

```
foo = Song(happy_bday.lyrics)
foo.sing_me_a_song()
```

The important bit is the `.lyrics`, if you don't include that, then it will give you a TypeError

Answer (score -1):

```
class Song(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.lyrics =(["Happy birthday to you",
                       "I don' want to get sued",
                       "So I'll stop right there",
                       "They rally around the family",
                       "With pockets full of shells"])

    def sing_me_a_song(self):
        for line in self.lyrics:
            print line 

happy_bday = Song()

happy_bday.sing_me_a_song()
```

Comment: "Put the lyrics in a separate variable, then pass that variable to the class to use instead."